# Multiple Alignment in MathJax

Tags: support, mathjax

What's the code for multiple alignment in MathJAX? An analogous question for Latex is at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43464/multiple-alignment-in-equations, but it doesn't appear to function here. Thank you.

> Objective:
>   $A = B$
>   $\qquad B = C$
>   $\qquad \qquad C = D$
>   $\qquad \qquad \qquad  E = F$

Attempt: 
$$\begin{align*} A = B\\\
&B = C\\\
&&C =D\\\ 
&&&E= F
\end{align*}$$

Code for Attempt: 
`$$\begin{align*} A = B\\\

&B = C\\\

&&C =D\\\

&&&E= F

\end{align*}$$`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option is to *abuse* the `alignat` environment.

```
$$\newcommand{\myeqa}{=}
    \begin{alignat}{5}
    A & \myeqa & B                                     \\
      &       & B & \myeqa & C                         \\
      &       &   &       & C & \myeqa & D             \\
      &       &   &       &   &       & D & \myeqa & E 
    \end{alignat}$$
```

To adjust spacing you can put spacing commands on either side of the equals sign, such as `\newcommand{\myeqa}{~=~}` instead to get some more spacing.

$$\newcommand{\myeqa}{=}
\begin{alignat}{5}
A & \myeqa & B                                     \\
  &       & B & \myeqa & C                         \\
  &       &   &       & C & \myeqa & D             \\
  &       &   &       &   &       & D & \myeqa & E 
\end{alignat}$$

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty hack-ish, but

```
$$\newcommand{\myeq}{\!\!=\!\!}
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
A & \myeq & B                                     \\
  &       & B & \myeq & C                         \\
  &       &   &       & C & \myeq & D             \\
  &       &   &       &   &       & D & \myeq & E 
\end{array}$$
```

produces

$$\newcommand{\myeq}{\!\!=\!\!}
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
A & \myeq & B                                     \\
  &       & B & \myeq & C                         \\
  &       &   &       & C & \myeq & D             \\
  &       &   &       &   &       & D & \myeq & E 
\end{array}$$
Is that like what you want?

Comment: Pretty doesn't come close to how hack-ish this is.

Comment: +1. Many thanks. Yes. Is there a way to lessen the space between the equal sign and the letters?